# MYSQL Update table with parameters from another table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to update a void field with an id from another table, that has a field with the id from the first table:

user:

- id_user
- some_fields
- id_account

account:

- id_account
- id_user
- some_fields

the id_user from the account table is already full, but I want to put the id_account to the first table, cause I have some users related to some account, but they are not owners of that account (Like parent's account and childs, linked to the parent's account).

The id_user from account is the owner of that account.

Any idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say your data model isn't exactly right. If you have a one-to-one relationship between  user and account, you need only carry the id_user on the account table and there's no need to have the id_account on the user table.

that said, with what you have now, this should update your columns:

```
update user u
set id_account = (select id_account from account a where a.id_user = u.id_user)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! it worked fine, now I just will add the id_account to the non-owner users manually and it will be all ok. 

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What if a person is related to more than one account (i.e. if it opens an account for 2 children)? The best solution would be to use another table:

```
UserAccountUnrelated

id_user
id_account
```

Comment: one person can only be attached to one account, and one account has one owner(one person) and can have more person attached to it.

I just want to copy the id from the account if the id_user from that account is the same as the user I update.

Comment: I still think your data model isn't accurate. But, if you want to attach persons to an account while they're not their owners, you will in fact need another entity - unless it's a 1-to-1 relationship as well.

Comment: BUT, the way you are doing it, a parent can be bound to only one child account. What if it has actually 2 or more childs whith accounts?